WebView2 highlight words in PDF
Using a WebView2 control in a .NET Framework 4.8 Solution with WPF.
To show a PDF we would generate a bit of HTML that looks like this:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow-y:hidden">
  <body style="height:100vh; width:100vw; margin:0px">
    <object data="https://somewhere.on.the.web/some.pdf" height="100%" width="100%" style="min-height:100vh; margin-bottom:50px" type="application/pdf">
    </object>
  </body>
</html>

This works perfectly
That said though, imagine the PDF contains a bunch of text including the word "Matter". To find this in the document, the user can go to the Viewer and find the Search icon:

And then they can type in a word to Search for and it will be highlighted for them:

My question: is it possible to include such a search term somewhere in the HTML so that the user won't need to type it in manually. I know that, for example, we can add a "Zoom" factor that way (add #zoom=value at the end of the data=[URL] attribute in the object node):
My google fu is failing me trying to find documentation for anything else we can add to the data attribute or the object node to allow us to pre-fill this "find" box. Any suggestions welcome.
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html style="overflow-y:hidden">
  <body style="height:100vh; width:100vw; margin:0px">
    <object data="https://somewhere.on.the.web/some.pdf#zoom=50" height="100%" width="100%" style="min-height:100vh; margin-bottom:50px" type="application/pdf">
    </object>
  </body>
</html>


Thanks @KJ ... Yes it does look like that question is similar even though I'm using an object tag rather than an embed and I guess the only reason I ended up posting this as a possible duplicate is that I was unable to find that one... I guess my "google fu" did fail me spectacularly alright. In any case I suspected that the correct answer would be "NO" alright, so thanks for confirming.

I see there was an option to accept your suggestion that this question was similar to the one you posted so I accepted it.
